# Is it possible to find a control in a XAML (Silverlight) using wildcard?

Tags: silverlight, wildcard, findcontrol

Is it possible to find a control in a XAML (Silverlight) using wildcard?

Ex.. in my XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="Title" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource txtBlock}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="uxTitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="{StaticResource IsControlReadOnly}"
                     Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource txtBox}" Width="100"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Firstname" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource txtBlock}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="uxFirstName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource txtBox}" Width="250"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Middlename" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource txtBlock}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="uxMiddleName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding MiddleName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource txtBox}" Width="250"/>
```

In Codebehind

```
public void searchControl()
{
      this.LayoutRoot.FindName("ux*");

      // Or like this way
      this.LayoutRoot.FindName("ux???");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could find helpful solution to this problem "[FindControl ID weirdness](http://forums.asp.net/t/1105743.aspx/1)"